# How am I misunderstanding trigger recursion in TSQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

**I have the following table:**

```
if object_id(N'dbo.Node') is null
create table dbo.Node
(
    ID bigint identity primary key,
    ParentID bigint null, -- references Node(ID)
    DateCreated datetime not null,
    LastUpdated datetime not null,
    [Name] nvarchar(500) not null,
);
```

**I have this trigger to achieve cascading deletes within the same table:**

```
create trigger Node_Delete on Node for delete
as
begin
    delete from Node where ParentID in (select id from deleted)
end
```

**Here's my data set:**

```
ID                   ParentID             DateCreated             LastUpdated             Name
534                  514                  2010-01-12 10:15:03.940 2010-01-12 10:15:03.940 Test 1
535                  534                  2010-01-12 10:15:08.563 2010-01-12 10:15:08.563 Test 2
536                  535                  2010-01-12 10:15:12.063 2010-01-12 10:15:12.063 Test 3
537                  536                  2010-01-12 10:15:18.510 2010-01-12 10:15:18.510 Test 4
```

**Now I perform this query:**

```
delete from Node where ID=534
```

**And this is the resultant data set:**

```
ID                   ParentID             DateCreated             LastUpdated             Name
536                  535                  2010-01-12 10:15:12.063 2010-01-12 10:15:12.063 Test 3
537                  536                  2010-01-12 10:15:18.510 2010-01-12 10:15:18.510 Test 4
```

**Why does the DELETE statement in the trigger not cause a recursive execution of the trigger until all descended records are deleted?**

EDIT: Note that I have posted a working solution below, but marked a different answer as correct, seeing as my question was not "what is the solution", but rather "why does the way I'm doing it not work".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to enable recursive triggers for the database. Notice that you can get only 32 levels deeper.

```
ALTER DATABASE databasename
SET RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS ON | OFF
```

Answer (score 4):

I modified my trigger to cascade to an unlimited depth without turning on trigger recursion. Here is my solution:

```
create trigger Node_Delete on Node instead of delete
as
begin
    create table #del ( id bigint, depth int )
    declare @depth int
    set @depth = 1
    insert into #del select id, @depth from deleted
    while @@rowcount > 0
    begin
        set @depth = @depth + 1
        insert into #del select id, @depth from Node where ParentID in (select id from #del where depth = @depth-1)
    end
    delete from Node where ID in (select id from #del)
end
```

EDIT: I've now settled on an even better solution using common table expressions, as suggested in another answer by Mladen Prajdic below.

```
create trigger Node_Delete on Node instead of delete
as
begin
    with nodes
    as
    (
        select n.ID, n.ParentID, 1 as Level
        from Node n where n.ID in (select ID from deleted)
        union all
        select n.ID, n.ParentID, p.Level+1 as Level
        from Node n
        inner join nodes p on p.ID = n.ParentID
    )
    delete from Node where ID in (select ID from nodes);
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Turn on nested triggers (or set the `Allow Triggers to Fire Others` option to True, depending on your sql version)

[sql server properties screenshot http://img34.imageshack.us/img34/5259/capturehjf.png](http://img34.imageshack.us/img34/5259/capturehjf.png)

Answer (score 1):

because the deleted pseudotable has only one row with id 534.

you could add a cascade delete on the parent-child relationship
or use a CTE to delete everything.

Comment: You can't add a cascade delete on the child-parent relationship because SQL Server complains about multiple cascade paths. Note that I updated how I was asking my question above. I don't understand why the trigger doesn't fire itself off due to the delete.

Comment: oh right. forgot about that. then you'll have to use CTE: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx

Comment: I can look up CTEs, but I still want to know why I can't do this with a trigger...

Comment: also you can set the Nested Triggers option: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178101.aspx but be carefull about this since it's a server wide setting and i wouldn't recommend it

Answer (score 1):

The FOR DELETE trigger is fired *after* the delete operation. Thus any child records violate the FK constraint, making the deletion impossible.

You can solve this by writing an [INSTEAD OF DELETE trigger](http://devio.wordpress.com/2008/05/23/recursive-delete-in-sql-server/) as decribed on my blog.